# Which permission do I have to add to the manifest to get gps sensor readings?

Tags: android, permissions, location, manifest

Which permission needs my application to get access to the location of the user on Android?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you need:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

outside the application tag in your AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: FINE_LOCATION will get you GPS
or android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION which i think will return GPS coords if available.  if not it will use wifi or cell-id
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION